# How can I find the xnu version that corresponds to a particular OS X release?

Tags: macos, darwin, xnu

I'm attempting to find the list of supported syscalls in an old version of OS X.

For each version of the XNU kernel, there is a `syscalls.master` file that gives me what I want (for example, [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-2782.20.48/bsd/kern/syscalls.master) is one for XNU 2782.20.48). I can see my current XNU version with `uname -a`. But I don't know how to find what version of XNU was included in historical releases of OS X.

Is there a list somewhere mapping OS X version number (e.g. 10.9.0) or build number to XNU version number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not perfect, but you can work it out from the Apple Open Source release listings at:

http://www.opensource.apple.com/

For each release linked (eg http://www.opensource.apple.com/release/os-x-10105/ for OSX 10.10.5), you have a link towards the bottom of the page for the XNU version for this release (eg, xnu-2782.40.9).

[@pajp](https://github.com/pajp) has gone to the effort of converting these tarballs into a useable git repo at:

https://github.com/aosm/xnu

with appropriate tagging for OSX release and XNU version, which you could use to put together a listing.

Comment: The second link is dead now.

Comment: Those links now 404, and I can't figure out how to get there navigating... - do you know where apple publishes this info now?